# Opinion/advice/knowledge/information: which to use?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, collocation, cloze-test

I chose a wrong answer in a test from http://www.cambridgeenglish.org

> According to Richard's _______ the train leaves at 7 o'clock.
>
> - opinion
> - advice
> - knowledge
> - information

I chose *knowledge.*

The right one is *information.* Could you tell me why?

Comment: Using *knowledge* still carries the possibility that that knowledge was not *expressed*. Whereas *opinion* and *advice* denote that the information was indeed expressed, but both explicitly carry the possibility that it was *incorrect*. I suggest you ask questions like this on our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: I'm a native English speaker, and I find this test question pretty ambiguous. I could probably argue that any one of them is correct, depending on the exact sense you're going for.

Comment: I'd just say *According to Richard*.

Answer (score 2):

knowledge: facts, information, and skills acquired by a person through experience or education.  Richard has knowledge about when the train leaves.

information: facts provided or learned about something or someone.  Richard supplied information about when the train leaves.

The key factor is that information is provided, while knowledge is simply known.  It doesn't help you that Richard has knowledge about the train schedule unless he informs you about it (provides you with the information).